# What will happen if I overstay in Prague, Czech Republic for 1 day?

Tags: air-travel, legal, overstaying, czech-republic, prague

I'd like to know what will happen if I overstay in Prague, Czech Republic for 1 day?

There was a confusion in the tour agency, and they filed one less day for Schengen visa.

I have visa to Schengen from 22-DEC-15 to 13-JAN-16 with duration of stay 8 days, and the flight back is on 30-DEC-15 (tickets are already purchased).
Shall I be fined, if yes how much, or even banned from re-entering Schengen for a year or more?

Comment: If you arrive on 22-DEC and leave on 39-DEC there's no overstay. Otherwise you'll have to rely on luck, charm and mercy of the imigration/border guard officer. Maybe you'll get away with having some explanation to do or you might get fined. Ban from Schengen is an unlikely penalty for just one day overastay.

Comment: Thank Egil, but the problem is that I have flight back on 30-DEC, in days it adds up to 9 days. Btw, is it possible to enter the airport on 8th day and get away from violating stay days period?

Comment: You could stay in the transit area, provided they'll allow you entry a day before the flight. You could ask at the airport, if you explain your situation they might be forthcoming.

Comment: Thank you once more. Your advices are helpful, they made me bit calmer :)

Comment: Another issue that the experts here might be able to advise you on: If you turn up at the border with a visa for 8 days, but a flight back on day 9, will they let you in?

Comment: That is the biggest question bothering me right now.. :(( Will they let me in at all. And I have already paid for hotel and tickets..

Comment: If your tour agency messed up, then you should get in touch with them immediately to get them to fix it. While they might not be able to do anything about your visa at short notice, they could change your flight to one that gets you out of the Schengen area within the 8 days you're allowed. Ideally this should be all done at their expense, if they are responsible for the mistake!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Overstaying  Penalties

Overstaying a visa, regardless of duration, is a serious offence and is therefore subject to penalties. [The possible penalties for overstaying a Schengen visa](http://www.euro-dollar-currency.com/overstaying_schengen_visa.htm) are (inversely ordered by severity):

- no penalty
- fine
- record
- ban
- deportation

Note that you can be subject to a combination of these. For example should you be deported you'll probably be recorded and banned too. Overall the applied penalties depend on a number of factors including the country in which you committed the offence and the individual immigration officer who deals with your case.

#### Your 1-Day Overstay

It is very difficult to predict which one will apply to a one day overstay. It'll probably depend on the immigration officers leniency and how well you can convince them that you didn't overstay intentionally. You can safely assume that if detected, the violation will be recorded and you're likely to be asked questions about it next time you apply for a Schengen visa.

To avoid overstaying you need to pass exit checks before 23:59:59 of the last visa validity day. You might want to try getting to the airport on that last visa validity day and see if you can make it past the checks on time.

Comment: It might be useful to note that this would also depend on the country (i.e. the penalty is *not* defined in EU law). A ban seems exceedingly unlikely in any case, in some countries even a fine is rather unlikely. Except if the visa is revoked and until a database of entries and exits is put in place, the violation would also not be recorded (beyond the stamps in the passport). I would consider being bounced back on entry more likely than any serious penalty when you are already on your way out.