# Less stay days than flight date in Schengen Zone

Tags: visas, schengen, overstaying

Is it possible that I am not allowed at all in Czech Republic because I have 8 stay days on visa and the flight back is one day later?

Comment: That is unlikely, but overstaying your visa is notva good idea.

Comment: How did you come to be in that position?

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60078/what-will-happen-if-i-overstay-in-prague-czech-republic-for-1-day - Apparently a screw up on the part of the tour operator.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible. Your visa is supposed to be valid for the whole duration of the stay and your return flight is *prima facie* evidence that you intend to stay longer than allowed (and also longer than what you claimed on your original application, which is not good either).

On the other hand, it's also possible that the border guards do not even notice or decide that one day is not serious enough to deny entry.

Even if you gain entry, it's also (theoretically) possible to be fined on exit (with the same caveats) and your passport will in any case bear stamps showing you did not fully respect the conditions of your visa, which might be a problem when you apply for another visa in the future (even a non-Schengen visa).

Obviously, overstaying by one day/a few hours is a relatively benign infringement and less likely to lead to serious consequences than staying for weeks or immigrating illegally but it's still a bad idea.

Comment: The problem with overstaying at this time is -- you are an illegal and if they want to demonstrate toughness on illegals (which, alas, in this Europe is a thing) you will be a very easy one.

Comment: Is it possible to apply for extra days during entry?

Comment: @WGrolean Not, there is no procedure for that and no notion of being granted a specific duration of stay upon entry in the Schengen area. You can request an extension of your visa during your stay – not specifically on entry – but you need a serious reason for that (e.g. you have to be hospitalised) and I don't think a mistake in the application would be enough.